# Pass mouse and keyboard input to background windows without losing focus

Tags: c++, windows, winapi

I'm developing a 3D desktop application [like this](http://blog.leapmotion.com/hood-leap-motion-hackathons-augmented-reality-workspace/) where I duplicate the desktop by creating planes in 3D space using each window's bitmap as texture and then passing mouse and keyboard input to them (background windows) via windows API.

This approach causes several issues and the main one is that some clicked windows generate new popup windows like menus that popup on top of 3D app and steal focus.
Is it possible to properly duplicate a desktop behavior inside another app like this - without losing focus and keeping 3D app on top?

Only workaround for this that I can think of is to have 3D app running on secondary monitor, let user work with regular desktop on primary monitor as usual and 3D app will just duplicate that and use windows hooks for any 3D app specific input.

Comment: Not possible. The only reliable way to generate input is by using `SendInput`. And that requires that the designated target is the foreground window. Which is something you do not want.

Comment: Are you trying to **send** input? Or are you trying to **receive** input while in the background? In the latter case, look at the [Raw Input API](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms645536.aspx).

Answer (score 0):

Apparently IInspectable is right. No reliable way to do this without losing focus.